# Running SQL, cannot get into

Tags: python, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I want to store retrieved data in a database of my choice in my laptop using Python?

Is there any setting and connection?

I had done:

```
pip install mysql.connector
```

following: [Python MySQL - CodersLegacy](https://coderslegacy.com/python/python-mysql/)[^]

After I had tried:

```
import mysql.connector
 
check = mysql.connector.connect(
    host= 'localhost',
    user = 'root',
    password = '12345678')
 
print(check)
```

It give me error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
&lt;ipython-input-4-e72118a94c51&gt; in &lt;module&gt;()
      3 check = mysql.connector.connect(
      4     host= 'localhost',
----&gt; 5     user = 'root')
      6 
      7 

C:\Users\id\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.pyc in connect(*args, **kwargs)
    177         return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
    178     else:
--&gt; 179         return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
    180 Connect = connect  # pylint: disable=C0103
    181 

C:\Users\id\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     93 
     94         if len(kwargs) &gt; 0:
---&gt; 95             self.connect(**kwargs)
     96 
     97     def _do_handshake(self):

C:\Users\id\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.pyc in connect(self, **kwargs)
    714 
    715         self.disconnect()
--&gt; 716         self._open_connection()
    717         self._post_connection()
    718 

C:\Users\id\AppData\Local\Continuum\
```

Comment: might want to use pyodbc instead.https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-MySQL

Comment: the code runs without problems, do you have a mysql database runnuing on your coumputer.

Comment: It's possible that you also need to specify the database parameter.

Comment: I just found this. https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/advanced-management-console-2/install-guide/mysql-database-installation-and-configuration-advanced-management-console.htm#JSAMI-GUID-00D8401C-C5EF-4F7C-B211-8B268BA0DB91

Before that, can I know can I setup MySQL database in my personal laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be because your connector does not specify the name of the database you want to connect to. The code works fine otherwise also but you might wanna try.
For example:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="12345678", 
  database="name_of_your_database"
)
print(mydb)
```

Comment: I get this error `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-659aa55258b4> in <module>()
      4   user="root",
      5   passwd="12345678",
----> 6   database="name_of_your_database"
      7 )
      8 print(mydb)`

Comment: Put the name of your database instead of `name_of_your_database`

Comment: If the connector object gets printed fine, that's your biggest hint!

Comment: do i need to install any tool for my MySQL?

Comment: Umm no, `pip install mysql.connector` This command works fine right? If yes then it should work. Also, your MySQL server must be running.

Comment: yes, the `pip` is working. I am using `ipython notebook`. is it not working in `ipython notebook`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218151/discussion-between-ayushi-desai-and-aan).